# Is Visa Debit more widely supported than Visa Electron?

Tags: visa

With Visa Electron bank account balance is checked before allowing a transaction to complete, but some (offline) payment systems may not be supported because verifying the availability of funds is not possible. Where I can expect to find Electron unsupported and can the coverage vary due to older infrastructure?

Comment: While I don't think this is off-topic here, you might get more helpful answers at the [Travel.SE] site. What country are you from, and where are you considering traveling to? I don't know what "Visa Electron" is, and from a quick Wikipedia check it's not a thing in my country.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr.: I'm from Finland and Electron is commonly used and a known card here, issued by the largest bank OP for instance. I expected Electron to be globally available in the countries Visa operates in.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Visa Electron is not available in the US, Canada, and a few other countries. Having lived in the US all my life, I can say I've never heard of Visa Electron, but don't know if they are technically supported just because they have the Visa logo or not. So you might need to narrow down your question to specific places you are considering traveling to see if you can expect your card will work there, rather than absolutely everywhere (which no current form of card can truly promise).

Answer (score 1):

> Is Visa Debit more widely supported than Visa Electron?

It seems yes, as Merchants would prefer to have Visa Debit as it allows for accounts to be overdrawn. As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Electron)

> Visa Electron is a debit card available across most of the world, with the exception of Canada, Australia, Ireland and the United States. The difference between Visa Electron and Visa Debit is that payments with Visa Electron require that all the funds be available at the time of transfer, i.e., Visa Electron card accounts may not normally be overdrawn. Visa Debit cards, on the other hand, typically allow transfers exceeding available funds up to a certain limit. Some online stores and all offline terminals (like on trains and aircraft) do not support Visa Electron because their systems cannot check for the availability of funds